# dgroup placing equation number on left side

Tags: math-mode, numbering, labels, breqn

I am using some equations that are auto-generated from a script and they are typeset using `breqn` functions.

Using `dgroup` is causing my equation number to be on the left side instead of right. I call the packages in this order, which should be correct as far as I could see from the documentation.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
```

The equations being typeset are

```
\begin{dgroup}
            \begin{dmath*}
                0=\frac{\partial }{\partial t} y_{2}\left(t\right)-\frac{\sin\left(y_{3}\left(t\right)\right)\cdot y_{5}\left(t\right)}{6371}
            \end{dmath*}
            \begin{dmath*}
                0=\frac{\cos\left(y_{3}\left(t\right)\right)\cdot y_{5}\left(t\right)}{6371}-\frac{\partial }{\partial t} y_{1}\left(t\right)
            \end{dmath*}
            \begin{dmath*}
                0=\frac{\cos\left(y_{3}\left(t\right)\right)\cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial t} y_{2}\left(t\right)}{\sin\left(y_{3}\left(t\right)\right)}-\frac{\partial }{\partial t} y_{1}\left(t\right)
            \end{dmath*}
            \begin{dmath*}
                0=y_{6}\left(t\right)-y_{5}\left(t\right)
            \end{dmath*}
            \begin{dmath*}
                0=y_{6}\left(t\right)-\frac{6371\cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial t} y_{2}\left(t\right)}{\sin\left(y_{3}\left(t\right)\right)}
            \end{dmath*}
            \begin{dmath*}
                0=y_{6}\left(t\right)-\frac{6371\cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial t} y_{1}\left(t\right)}{\cos\left(y_{3}\left(t\right)\right)}
            \end{dmath*}
            \begin{dmath*}
                0=y_{4}\left(t\right)-y_{3}\left(t\right)
            \end{dmath*}
            \begin{dmath*}
                0=\frac{\sin\left(y_{4}\left(t\right)\right)\cdot y_{5}\left(t\right)}{6371}-\frac{\partial }{\partial t} y_{2}\left(t\right)
            \end{dmath*}
            \begin{dmath*}
                0=\frac{\cos\left(y_{4}\left(t\right)\right)\cdot y_{5}\left(t\right)}{6371}-\frac{\partial }{\partial t} y_{1}\left(t\right)
            \end{dmath*}
            \begin{dmath*}
                0=\frac{\cos\left(y_{4}\left(t\right)\right)\cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial t} y_{2}\left(t\right)}{\sin\left(y_{4}\left(t\right)\right)}-\frac{\partial }{\partial t} y_{1}\left(t\right)
            \end{dmath*}
            \begin{dmath*}
                0=y_{6}\left(t\right)-\frac{6371\cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial t} y_{2}\left(t\right)}{\sin\left(y_{4}\left(t\right)\right)}
            \end{dmath*}
            \begin{dmath*}
                0=y_{6}\left(t\right)-\frac{6371\cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial t} y_{1}\left(t\right)}{\cos\left(y_{4}\left(t\right)\right)}
            \end{dmath*}
        \end{dgroup}
```

Comment: You mention, "I am using some equations that are auto-generated from a script and they are typeset using breqn functions". Since no automatic line breaking is required in any of the 12 individual equations, can you modify the script to make it use the much simpler `split` machinery of the `amsmath` package?  While you're at it, can you modify the script to replace all instances of `\left(t\right)` with `(t)`?

Comment: I would like to avoid modifying the script as long as its possible, I should've mentioned that in the original post. In addition it may be that automatic line breaking is not necessary here, but it is in other instances.

Answer (score 2):

Not a solution, but this seems to be a known bug in `breqn`, see page 5 of the [package manual](http://mirror.neu.edu.cn/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/breqn/breqn.pdf):

[image]

So, for now you can't achieve exactly what you want the way you do it. I will check if I can come back with a workaround.

O.K, here is a not-so-elegant workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\parbox{.9\linewidth}{%
\begin{dgroup*}
    \begin{dmath*}
        0=\frac{\partial }{\partial t} y_{2}\left(t\right)-\frac{\sin\left(y_{3}\left(t\right)\right)\cdot y_{5}\left(t\right)}{6371}
    \end{dmath*}
    \begin{dmath*}
        0=\frac{\cos\left(y_{3}\left(t\right)\right)\cdot y_{5}\left(t\right)}{6371}-\frac{\partial }{\partial t} y_{1}\left(t\right)
    \end{dmath*}
    \begin{dmath*}
        0=\frac{\cos\left(y_{3}\left(t\right)\right)\cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial t} y_{2}\left(t\right)}{\sin\left(y_{3}\left(t\right)\right)}-\frac{\partial }{\partial t} y_{1}\left(t\right)
    \end{dmath*}
    \begin{dmath*}
        0=y_{6}\left(t\right)-y_{5}\left(t\right)
    \end{dmath*}
    \begin{dmath*}
        0=y_{6}\left(t\right)-\frac{6371\cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial t} y_{2}\left(t\right)}{\sin\left(y_{3}\left(t\right)\right)}
    \end{dmath*}
    \begin{dmath*}
        0=y_{6}\left(t\right)-\frac{6371\cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial t} y_{1}\left(t\right)}{\cos\left(y_{3}\left(t\right)\right)}
    \end{dmath*}
    \begin{dmath*}
        0=y_{4}\left(t\right)-y_{3}\left(t\right)
    \end{dmath*}
    \begin{dmath*}
        0=\frac{\sin\left(y_{4}\left(t\right)\right)\cdot y_{5}\left(t\right)}{6371}-\frac{\partial }{\partial t} y_{2}\left(t\right)
    \end{dmath*}
    \begin{dmath*}
        0=\frac{\cos\left(y_{4}\left(t\right)\right)\cdot y_{5}\left(t\right)}{6371}-\frac{\partial }{\partial t} y_{1}\left(t\right)
    \end{dmath*}
    \begin{dmath*}
        0=\frac{\cos\left(y_{4}\left(t\right)\right)\cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial t} y_{2}\left(t\right)}{\sin\left(y_{4}\left(t\right)\right)}-\frac{\partial }{\partial t} y_{1}\left(t\right)
    \end{dmath*}
    \begin{dmath*}
        0=y_{6}\left(t\right)-\frac{6371\cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial t} y_{2}\left(t\right)}{\sin\left(y_{4}\left(t\right)\right)}
    \end{dmath*}
    \begin{dmath*}
        0=y_{6}\left(t\right)-\frac{6371\cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial t} y_{1}\left(t\right)}{\cos\left(y_{4}\left(t\right)\right)}
    \end{dmath*}
\end{dgroup*}
}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried to put `\tag` but it not works. +1.